# Android Printing, why do I get warning when i try to print from my mobile

Tags: android, printing

When i try to print from my Android device I see a dialog prompt with a message Your document may pass through **one or more servers** on its way to the printer.

This dialog appears too when I enable/re-enable any print service from settings.

Does any one know what does Android mean by **one or more servers**?

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the fact that most of all printers in normal households are linked over a router wich enables all devices in this household to use the printer.
So your router is a kind of server.
In bigger companis there are sometimes more of these connected to each other so it can pass "more" servers.
It's totally normal and not dangerous.

Comment: thanks for quick response. does all Android OS show up this message, i checked its there on Android M, N and O, Does older version(K,L) also show this message?

Answer (score 2):

Some print services rely on a cloud service for printing. The Android OS can't tell whether a given print service will do this, hence the generic error message. (Note that later Android OS versions do not have this message.)